# Predict new coordinates given old coordinates in Tensorflow's Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

The goal is to be able to predict a new set of (x1, y1), (x2, y2) coordinates when given the old set of (x1, y1), (x2, y2) coordinates.

That is to say, if my old coordinates are (0, 0), (4, 4), I want to get an output like (2, 3, 8, 9) where the numbers correspond to (x1, y1, x2, y2).

Only, I have no idea how to get multiple numerical outputs like that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use sequential models. As I understand you have inputs with size 4, and outputs with size 4 as well. In this case you would do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential(
    [ 
        
        layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="layer1", input_shape=(4,)),
        layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer3"),
        layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="layer4"),
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
```

[image]

And then you can train your model. However you need to adjust params and structure of the model for your own data.